# How to add a calendar icon inside the input text element

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, daterangepicker

I wanna know how I can input the icon from font awesome inside the textbox in daterangepicker
 just like this:
[image]

because i'm only getting this:

[image]

This is my HTML code below:

```
<div class="container content-header">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <i class = "fas fa-calendar"></i><input type="text" id="daterange">
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I'm building a Codepen example for you, but this should help: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/css-to-put-icon-inside-an-input-element-in-a-form/

Answer (score 3):

```css
/* Just to space the input away from the very top of the result field */
.content-header {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
/* */

.input-icons i { 
    position: absolute;
} 

.input-icons { 
    width: 100%; 
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
} 

.icon { 
    padding: 15px;
} 

.input-field { 
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head> 
  
<body> 
  <div class="container content-header">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="input-icons">
              <i class = "fa fa-calendar icon"></i>
              <input class="input-field text-center" type="text" id="daterange" placeholder="Some Placeholder" size="35">
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Here is a sample, just make your customizations to get it sized and aligned to fit your needs: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/jeffberlin/pen/KKdyvpy?editors=1100)

And keep in mind next time you ask for help on StackOverflow, to provide as much info as you can (code, project info, what you've already tried, etc.). Since you've posted no CSS, we all assume there is nothing in your code that will override what is working for everyone else.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```css
.icons i {
  position: absolute;
}

.fas {
  padding: 10px;
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container content-header">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 icons">
      <i class="fas fa-calendar calendar"></i><input type="text" id="daterange" class="input-field">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```